# EF Core - Can we specify the entity set to be queried dynamically in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

The app I'm building handles devices that are rented out by the company to distributors. The distributors then rent them out to charities (known internally as causes).

I'm trying to write a Linq query that will give me a list of rentals. These can either be distributor rentals or cause rentals. In either case, the query is to return a list of `Rental` objects, where `Rental` is a DTO.

I have the query below, but as you can see, there is a lot of repetition.

```cs
Rentals = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DistributorId)
  ? (await AppDbContext.DistributorRentals.Include(dr => dr.Device).Include(dr => dr.Distributor)
    .OrderBy(dr => dr.Start)
    .ToListAsync())
  .Where(dr => IsRentedOnDate(dr.Device, startOfMonth) || dr.Start >= startOfMonth)
  .Select(dr => new Rental {
    Start = dr.Start,
    End = dr.End,
    Device = dr.Device.SerialNumber,
    Recipient = dr.Distributor.Name
  })
  .ToObservableCollection()
  : (await AppDbContext.CauseRentals.Include(cr => cr.Device).Include(cr => cr.Cause)
    .Where(cr => cr.DistributorRental.DistributorId == DistributorId)
    .OrderBy(cr => cr.Start)
    .ToListAsync())
  .Where(cr => IsRentedOnDate(cr.Device, startOfMonth) || cr.Start >= startOfMonth)
  .Select(cr => new Rental {
    Start = cr.Start,
    End = cr.End,
    Device = cr.Device.SerialNumber,
    Recipient = cr.Cause.Name
  })
  .ToObservableCollection();
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to reduce this. The only real differences are...

1. The `DbSet` being queried, which is either `Distributors` or `Causes`, depending on whether the `DistributorId` property has a value
2. The second `Include`s are different
3. The cause query includes a `Where` to get rentals just for that distributor, whereas the distributor query does not need this
4. The `recipient` property in the final `Select` uses either the `Distributor` or `Cause` as appropriate.

Any suggestions as to how I could reduce the repetition in this code?

Comment: What is `IsRentedOnDate`, show method.

Comment: In my opinion, the only way for this to be possible is to create a generic repository/repository pattern.

Comment: @CarloLuisito, generic repository is anti-pattern with EF Core and for sure it will not help here.

Comment: We can simplify this, bad here that you are loading whole table into the memory including `Device` record. I see problem with function `IsRentedOnDate`, which will be not translatable.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I didn't show `IsRentedOnDate` as it's not relevant to my question. I did intend to comment that it's not translatable, which is why it has to be after `ToListAsync`. I am aware that this loads the whole table into memory, but without some way of translating `IsRentedOnDate`, I can't (yet) see any way around it.